# Insert an Azure Slot Setting into a Javascript File

Tags: azure, continuous-deployment

Is there a way, possibly in `deploy.cmd`, to alter the contents of a file?  Either ALL of the contents, or Search and Replace, or Grep, or anything?

I need a way to alter an environment variable in a javascript file based on a Slot Setting in Azure.

Or, put another way: I want to take a Slot Setting in an Azure slot, and insert it into a javascript file.

Comment: This sounds like you are trying to do something not the way it should be done. Can you explain a little more? Are you saying that you have a Slot setting in azure portal and you want to read it in your code?

Comment: @RAS I am not currently doing, or trying to do, anything.  So there is no way it's "not the way it should be done."  I'm asking for the way to do it.  And yes, I am trying to use Slot Settings in different environment slots in order for my app to have different settings in different environments.  I'd like to do it as native to Azure as possible and not pull in other tools like Octopus.

Answer (score 0):

No sure why you want to inject those values in the runtime instead of during build and deployment. But here are a few possible solutions:

1. Azure App Service slot settings are exposed as environment variables, your javascript could make an ajax call back to the server to an API you develop that can return the values of those environment variables.
2. Inject the value from your app's backend before serving the JS file to the client on the fly (and maybe cache it), in this case, you have to intercept the request for that file and serve your modified version.
3. Add a json file to your website, let's call it config.json, and change its content for each slot based on your requirements. Then your JavaScript app can read that file by issuing an AJAX GET to /config.json, which will represent the slot config.

Comment: Thanks.  Those are both options.  The problem is: The exact thing I'm trying to alter/inject into the javascript is a URL to point to Which API to pull settings from.  That URL is **not** the same URL as the URL the page is running on.  Also, the site is just HTML.  Not asp.net, coldfusion, php, or any other dynamic backend language.

Comment: The only other option is to inject this value during your build or deployment process. Do you use any CI/CD tools?

Comment: Also, I am not trying to do this at runtime at all.  The whole point and description of my post is to do it during the deploy.cmd deployment phase.  But I am open to any (azure) way to read those settings from Azure into my javascript.  I try not to bring up Octopus Deploy because I try to stay pure before considering pulling in yet another tool.

Comment: Another option could be uploading a static JSON file to your app service that contains the config values and load it from your JavaScript

Comment: If you mean an App Service, as in a Javascript "Service", then that would require me to parse a URL to determine which JSON to use.  Parsing the URL sounds dirty.  If you mean some RESTful API, then that doesn't work because I don't know the URL.  That URL is the thing I'm trying to inject.

Comment: An app service in Azure is the hosting plan that contains your websites and their slots. What I was suggesting is that you add a json file to your website, let's call it /config.json and to change its content for each slot based on your requirements and then you JavaScript can read that file by issuing an Ajax GET request to the local /config.json, which represents the slot configuration

Comment: Awesome.  Can you please elaborate in your answer how my javascript will know which part of the config.json (or which config.json) to use based on the slot?